# Checksum and pipe an input simultaneously

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, checksum

I want to securely move a big file from one computer to another, where it have to be processed before being stored.

I thought to pipe file into ssh running the processing script.

```
local.example.com$ cat file | ssh remote.example.com process.sh
```

(If you have any idea better than mine, please suggest)

In the process script i want to both checksum and encrypt the file before saving it. And here comes the problem.

Solutions may be two:

- pipe input into two commands (cksum and openssl); but all ways I found looked complicated and sub-optional.
- hack cksum to also do a cat-like work and print result on stderr, so that I can do

  ```
  cksum --pipe | openssl enc > myfile
  ```

  and get the checksum back via stderr.
  Unfortunately, I looked into the code and it seems hard for me to do that without doing some performance/buffering damage ;)

There may be a cksumming-transfering tool that does this all, but it didn't come me to mind.
Anyway I want to avoid non-standard and complex stuff.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: useful link about answer http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start off your receiving script with `cat > inputfile`, that will eat all STDIN until EOF, then your script can run any actions needed on inputfile.

You can also use `tee`:

```
echo foo | tee >(sha1sum) >(md5sum)
foo
d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00  -
f1d2d2f924e986ac86fdf7b36c94bcdf32beec15  -
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that require storing input in a file _before_ processing and as I want to perform stream operations (RC4 and CRC) that would be sub-optimal, no?

Comment: You could also use `tee` with process redirection. I'll edit and add an example.

Comment: That's it! I looked at `tee` but I didn't know about process redirection. Do you think there will be performance drops in process redirection or ssh piping?

Comment: @FileSottile, if this answers your question then you should accept it to give Daenyth proper credit.

Comment: @FiloSottile: There is some (very) minor overhead in forking processes -- we're talking milliseconds. Unless this is inside a tight inner loop and repeats often, you will be fine. Make it work first, then profile the code if it's slow.

Comment: @glenn-jackman Yeah, I know, but I was doing some tests to ensure that streams are handled correctly (simultaneously). And they are! So, accept!

Comment: Great, I don't have similar problems, only a big file, so is important the I/O performance. Thank you very much, I got it working in a second =)